# How to construct the address of a table in another workbook to use for structured references

Tags: excel, vba

I need to transfer data from a source table in the source workbook to export tables in various worksheets of an export workbook using structured table  references. I first have to determine the name of current export table and find the next empty row in that table, but I have a problem constructing the export table address to use with structured table references. The VBA project is in the source workbook. I start with the following code (Exp for Export):

```
    Dim wbExp as Workbook, wsExp as Worksheet, tblExp as ListObject
    Dim tblName as String, r as Range, rw as Integer

    set wbExp = Workbooks("Export_Workbook_Address")
    set wsExp = wbExp.Worksheets("Current_Export_Worksheet_Name")

    wsExp.activate
    Range{"A3").Activate  'First data cell in the current export table
    tblName = ActiveCell.ListObject.Name  'Current export table name
    set tblExp = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tblName)  'Current export table
    rw = 1
    For Each r in [tblExp[Column1]]
       If [tblExp[@Column1]] = vbNullString Then  'First empty row found
          Exit For  
       Else
          rw = rw + 1
       End If
    Next r
    ...
```

Although tblExp has the identical structure and .Name as the actual table whose name is tblJan, I get the error "Object required" at

```
    For Each r in [tblExp[Column1]]
```

probably because tblExp is not in the Excel Name Manager, i.e. tblExp is not recognized as an alias for tblJan. If I use tblJan instead of tblExp, the code works. But as the code has to access tables with different names in other worksheets, it needs to use the generic name tblExp for all, because I don't have control of the export table names.

So the question is how to make tblExp refer to tblJan, once I have the latter's name in tblName? I could write code to temporarily rename tblJan to tblExp in the Name Manager, but I'm looking for a more straightforward solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is a typo in `Range{` where you use the curly brace `{`, which should be `(`

Comment: In `set wbExp = Workbooks("Export_Workbook_Address")` you need to include the filename extension, e.g. `set wbExp = Workbooks("Export_Workbook_Address.xls")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to renaming the actual export table name in the export workbook from e.g. tblJan to generic tblExp for use in structured table references was in front of my nose:

```
Dim wbExp as Workbook, wsExp as Worksheet, tblExp as ListObject
Dim tblName as String, r as Range, rw as Integer, 

set wbExp = Workbooks("Export_Workbook.xlsx")
set wsExp = wbExp.Worksheets("Jan")  'Current export worksheet

wsExp.activate
Range{"A3").Activate  'First data cell in current export table
tblName = ActiveCell.ListObject.Name  'Current export table name
set tblExp = wsExp.ListObjects(tblName)  'Current export table
tblExp.Name = "tblExp"  'Rename to generic table name

rw = 1
For Each r in [tblExp[Column1]]
   If [tblExp[@Column1]] = vbNullString Then  'First empty row found
      Exit For  
   Else
      rw = rw + 1
   End If
Next r
...
'Data export with structured table references using [tblExp[...]]
...
set tblExp.Name = tblName  'Restore original table name when finished
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I find it strange that your VB compiler didn't warn you about syntax errors. Also, I and my VB compiler (2008) have problems working with the square brackets syntax.

The following code works to a large extend. I couldn't test the code inside the `For Each` loop because I have no `ListObject` table.

```
Dim wbExp As Workbook, wsExp As Worksheet, tblExp As ListObject
Dim tblName As String, r As Range, rw As Integer

Set wbExp = Workbooks("myWorkbook.xls")    ' note the filename extension
Set wsExp = wbExp.Worksheets("Sheet2")

wsExp.Activate
Range("A3").Activate                       ' syntax error removed: { replaced with (
tblName = ActiveCell.ListObject.Name
Set tblExp = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tblName)
rw = 1
For Each r In tblExp.ListRows              ' syntax to iterate over the rows
   If r.Value = vbNullString Then          ' syntax to check for null row
      Exit For
   Else
      rw = rw + 1
   End If
Next r
```

Comment: I'm in Excel 2016 with structured table references using square brackets. Your If statement generates the error "Type mismatch"

Comment: If the `If` statement you are referring to is within the `For Each` block, then yes, that is possible because, as I wrote, I could not test inside that block. You'll have to solve that problem yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Paul. But as I need to be able to use structured table references to be consistent throughout all programs that use tables, I found a simple solution that was in front of my nose.